# Installing interim fix DominoServer_90IF5_W64 stops when clicking Next button

Tags: ibm-domino

I'm trying to install Domino 9.0 IF5 in Win64 to fix this vulnerability:

> [CVE-2013-5388] Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in iNotes in
>   IBM Domino 8.5.3 before FP5 IF2 and 9.0 before IF5 allows remote
>   attackers to inject arbitrary web script or HTML via unspecified
>   vectors, aka SPR PTHN9AYK5F.

The installer is *90HF888_W64.exe*. It starts fine and confirms the location of Domino installation. But when I click "Next" at that point the installer just closes. I run it first by double clicking it and later I also tried "Run as administrator".

I've shut down Domino and Domino Diagnostics services and also shut down "Windows Management Instrumentation" service as someone recommended.

I'm connecting with Windows Remote Desktop with */ADMIN /CONSOLE* command line options.

Is there a log somewhere that shows what went wrong or how can I try to solve this?

**Edit**

Looks like we are going to install 9.0.1FP2 instead. I hope that goes smoothly.

Comment: Did you start it with "run as administrator" ?

Comment: No, I will try it thanks. Never needed to do that before. Updated the question.

Comment: "run as administrator" did not help - the result is the same. Editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is 32-bit. It seems that the 64-bit version installer is 32-bit because it run through a few phases before quitting.

The 32-bit interim fix installed fine.